# How to add SSL to Github page that set to subdomain that is completely separate from main domain)?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, github-pages

Here is my current set up.

- Domain from Godaddy
- Hosting on Digital Ocean (A record points to Droplet IP) with Let's encrypt SSL

It is working fine and I don't really want to change much of that but all the solutions I have researched involve the changes from current setting I have now.

**What I want to do is**

- Set up Github page
- Add subdomain in Godaddy and point that to Github page
- Add a free SSL to it

I have a page set up working with subdomain(http://onestory.goodnightjournal.com/) but can't find solution to add a free SSL to the page without changing any settings that I currently have for main domain.